# Calling a function inheriting onlyOwner via other contract

Tags: solidity, erc-721, modifiers

I need to call `mint()` function in **MyNFToken.sol** via **MyContract.sol**.

**Ownable.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract Ownable {

address public owner;

function Ownable()
public
{
  owner = msg.sender;

}


 modifier onlyOwner() {

  require(msg.sender == owner);
_;
  }


}
```

**MyNFToken.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

import "../tokens/NFTokenMetadata.sol";
import "../../node_modules/@0xcert/ethereum-utils/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";


contract MyNFToken is
  NFTokenMetadata,
  Ownable

{

function MyNFToken(
    string _name,
    string _symbol
)
public
{
     nftName = _name;
     nftSymbol = _symbol;
  }

function mint(
    address _owner,
    uint256 _id
)
 onlyOwner
 external
{
    super._mint(_owner, _id);
 }

}
```

**MyContract.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

import "../tokens/MyNFToken.sol";


 contract MyContract{

address nftaddress;

function MyContract (address _nftaddress) public {
    nftaddress = _nftaddress;

}

 function createToken(address _owner,uint256 _tokenId) onlyOwner public payable returns(bool){

    MyNFToken instance = MyNFToken(nftaddress);
    instance.mint(_owner,_tokenId);
    return true;
}
```

I'm able to execute `mint()` directly from **MYNFToken.sol** by accurately    checking the owner of contract(Ownable.sol). But not able call `mint()` via **MyContract.sol**. Is there something missing or beyond my understanding?..Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `mint()` in **MyNFToken.sol**, `msg.sender` is your address since you call it directly. When calling it from **MyContract.sol** - the sender is **MyContract.sol** contract and it is not the owner of **MyNFToken.sol** so `onlyOwner` modifier reverts.
If you want it work you should take `address` parameter `mint(address _caller)` and pass `msg.sender` from **MyContract.sol**, then check if `_caller` is `owner` in **MYNFToken.sol**, either in function or in modifier.

**EDIT**. You could do it like this if you call `mint()` from other contract:

**MyNFToken.sol**

```
function mint(address _sender, address _owner, uint256 _id) external
{
    require(_sender == owner);
    super._mint(_owner, _id);
}
```

**MyContract.sol**

```
function createToken(address _owner,uint256 _tokenId) onlyOwner public payable returns(bool){

    MyNFToken instance = MyNFToken(nftaddress);
    instance.mint(msg.sender, _owner,_tokenId);
    return true;
}
```

Also consider using interfaces if you are only using function or two of other contract, as it will save gas when creating contract and allow to have more code in current contract.

**EDIT EDIT.** Alternatively you could do this to avoid passing address:

**MyNFToken.sol**

```
address myContract;
function mint(address _owner, uint256 _id) external
{
    require(msg.sender == owner || msg.sender == myContract);
    super._mint(_owner, _id);
}
```

**MyContract.sol**

```
function createToken(address _owner,uint256 _tokenId) onlyOwner public payable returns(bool){

    MyNFToken instance = MyNFToken(nftaddress);
    instance.mint(_owner,_tokenId);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks...You meant the parameter of `mint(_owner, _tokenid)`. Here `_owner` is passed from js which is given same value of `msg.sender` . Also **MyContract.sol** and **MYNFToken.sol**  is deployed by same wallet address hence, the owner of both contracts is same...right? Can you please explain a bit more

Comment: Edited my answer.